# Replacing 3 line string

Tags: python, python-re

When calling external API I get this kind of response It is 2 lines of 44 characters total 88. Which is perfect.

```
r.text = "P<RUSBASZNAGDCIEWS<<AZIZAS<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"
           "00000000<ORUS5911239F160828525911531023<<<10"
```

But some times I get this kind of response and I need to make it the same as in example 1. 2 lines of 44 characters.
All this big `く` should be replaced with normal `<` and spaces also removed

```
r.text = "P<RUSALUZAFEE<<ZUZILLAS<<<<
          くくくくくくくくくく、
          00000000<ORUS7803118 F210127747803111025<<<64"
```

expected OUTPUT:

```
string =  "P<RUSALUZAFEE<<ZUZILLAS<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          00000000<ORUS7803118F210127747803111025<<<64"
```

Comment: There's also a `、` after the malformed `く`s. Also, replacing those 10 `く`s doesn't yield you 88 characters anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is best attempt guess you will find it helpful

```
import re

txt =""" P<RUSALUZAFEE<<ZUZILLAS<<<<
    くくくくくくくくくく、
    00000000<ORUS7803118 F210127747803111025<<<64"""

txt_1 = re.sub('(く |く)', '<', txt).replace('、','')
txt_2 = re.sub(r'\s+', '', txt_1)
regex = r"(\w<?\w+<+\w+<+)(\w*<?\w+<+\w+)"
result = re.match(regex, txt_2)
print(f'{result.group(1)}\n{result.group(2)}')
```

Output

```
P<RUSALUZAFEE<<ZUZILLAS<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
00000000<ORUS7803118F210127747803111025<<<64
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with re.sub from the module re like the following

```
new_txt = re.sub("<", "く", old_txt)
```

or with str.replace like the following

```
new_str = OldStr.replace("く", "<")
```

or use regex and combine it with if else like

```
 if pattern:
       re.sub  # or str.replace
   else:
       pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import re

pattern = r'\n.*く.*\n'
s = re.compile(pattern)
string = s.sub('\n', r.text)
```